# Switch to landscape for one or more pages in ConTeXt

Tags: context-mkiv

I tried the following code. I cannot figure out why the page size remains the same. As such, the papersize remains A4 portrait instead of switching to landscape.

```
\definepapersize[standing][A4]          [A4]
\definepapersize[lying]   [A4,landscape][A4,landscape]

\showframe

\starttext
  \setuppapersize[standing]
  Page 1: standing pages from here on. \page
  Page 2. \page
  \setuppapersize[lying]
  Page 3: lying pages from here on. \page
  Page 4. \page
  \adaptpapersize[standing]
  Page 5: adapted to standing \page
  Page 6: automatically back to lying \page
\stoptext
```

[image: PDF Page size wrong]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works in TL2016.